# Loop for reading and saving .dbc and .csv files respectively

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a loop that reads dbc files and converts them to .csv, but when I run it, an error appears: Error in dbc2dbf(file, out) : error decompressing file: -1. what is this?

```
nomes  <- c(
"DNAC2013.dbc", "DNAC2014.dbc", "DNAC2015.dbc", "DNAC2016.dbc", "DNAC2017.dbc", "DNAC2018.dbc", "DNAC2019.dbc", "DNAC2020.dbc", "DNAC2021.dbc",
"DNAL2013.dbc", "DNAL2014.dbc", "DNAL2015.dbc", "DNAL2016.dbc", "DNAL2017.dbc", "DNAL2018.dbc", "DNAL2019.dbc", "DNAL2020.dbc", "DNAL2021.dbc",
"DNAM2013.dbc", "DNAM2014.dbc", "DNAM2015.dbc", "DNAM2016.dbc", "DNAM2017.dbc", "DNAM2018.dbc", "DNAM2019.dbc", "DNAM2020.dbc", "DNAM2021.dbc",
"DNAP2013.dbc", "DNAP2014.dbc", "DNAP2015.dbc", "DNAP2016.dbc", "DNAP2017.dbc", "DNAP2018.dbc", "DNAP2019.dbc", "DNAP2020.dbc", "DNAP2021.dbc",
....
)

# Directory where the files are located
diretorio <- "C:/Users/dossa/Downloads/arquivo (1)/vivos/"

# Loop to read and save files
for (nome in nomes) {
  caminho <- paste0(diretorio, nome)
  x <- read.dbc(caminho)
  
  # Remove the .DBC or .dbc extension and add .csv
  nome_csv <- gsub("\\.dbc$", ".csv", nome)
  
  # Define the path to save with the .csv extension
  caminho_csv <- paste(diretorio, nome_csv, sep = "/")
  
  # Save the file as CSV
  write.csv(x, file = caminho_csv)
}
```

Comment: According to the documentation, `read.dbc` first decompresses the file and outputs a .dbf file. This is done with function `dbc2dbf` and that's what giving you an error. Are all files giving errors?

Comment: Also, is your working directory the directory where the files are? Try using full path names and see if the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer but try the following code to see which files are giving errors and which are being read and written as csv files. The call to `read.dbc` is in a `tryCatch` statement and errors are returned in a list. That list is tested after the `for` loop.

Note that I have removed the last `"/"` from `diretorio`. This is because I am using `file.path` to assemble the file names from their directory and basenames.

```
diretorio <- "C:/Users/dossa/Downloads/arquivo (1)/vivos"

# list to hold read.dbc errors, if any
err_list <- vector("list", length(nomes)) |> setNames(nomes)
# Loop to read and save files
for(nome in nomes) {
  caminho <- file.path(diretorio, nome)
  x <- tryCatch(read.dbc(caminho), error = function(e) e)
  
  if(!inherits(x, "error")) {
    # Remove the .DBC or .dbc extension and add .csv
    nome_csv <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(nome) |> paste0(".csv")
    
    # Define the path to save with the .csv extension
    caminho_csv <- file.path(diretorio, nome_csv)
    
    # Save the file as CSV
    write.csv(x, file = caminho_csv)
    err_list[[nome]] <- "ok"
  } else err_list[[nome]] <- e
}

err <- sapply(err_list, inherits, "error")
nomes[err]
```